# Am I able to see the total number of applicants for a Stack Overflow job?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Similar to LinkedIn, is it possible to know how many applicants have applied for a job on the Stack Overflow jobs site?

Comment: I would imagine that the recruiters would know this information, but why do you think this is a significant detail as an applicant?

Comment: To know the number of developers I am competing with

Comment: This sounds like something a dishonest company might seek to bump up.

Comment: As a recruiter, I don't see this as a competition with a winner. If I do not find the profile that fit the company needs I would not hire one just because I place the role. It's not like I will hire the best among those ones that apply, is more like I will hire the one that fits the role, so the competition is against your self only.

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida Is recruiting this cut and dry? I think it is an oversimplification to say that there will only be one applicant that fits the role they are applying for. Therefore, more applicants with similar skills sets would mean higher competition. Otherwise why would companies interview more than one person? Plus more applications means less attention paid to each one.

Comment: Additionally, most recruiters take the quality over quantity stance, as it means less work overall for them; just throw them all at the company, let them decide who they want.  Not saying you're that kind of recruiter, @Bruno, but there's going to be more of that type than the ethical ones.

Comment: @qurban Why does it matter to you how much competition there is?  Either you are going to apply or you won't.  If you apply, you have a chance of getting the job.  If you don't, you don't.  It will take you more time to second guess your chances than it does to just submit a CV and be done with it.

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida It seems to me that this feature would be relevant for potential candidates, it doesn't seem to be bad or good from the recruiter point of view. At most, it would prevent a recruiter from *lying* for negotiations reasons, as noted in a previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

Besides some of the concerns brought up in the discussion already, one of the reasons we don’t do this is because we often don’t have that data. We support a few different methods for managing applications including an “external apply flow”, where candidates are redirected to the employer’s site to submit their application. A lot of our jobs are set up this way, and in such cases, we don’t see the exact number of submitted applications.

Reading through the discussion, it sounds like the main motivation behind this request is to get a sense of the competition for a given position. Currently, we show “Be one of the first applicants” badges on listings that we estimate haven’t received any applications:

[image: example showing badge]

It’s even possible to filter job search results to only show listings with this badge:

[image: example showing filter]

That said, there’s definitely more we could do on this front. It’s not something that’s currently on our roadmap, but if we see more requests for it, we’ll revisit this later in the year.

Comment: Is there any chance that this has been revisited, at this moment in time even approximations such as '~15 applicants' might be something to consider.

Answer (score 7):

Again, as I can't comment, I will try to answer here.

@Chabo. I did not say that there is only one fit. I am saying that knowing the number of people that have applied to a role "as a matter of competition" is not a good approach as the application is only the phase 1 and it depends, almost only if you have a match or not. After that other qualification will be evaluated, by the headhunter, by the team or by whoever does that.

@fbueckert. This is one of the approaches that may be applied to the process, each company has its own.

The main argument I was trying to say is "you are not going to give up at your dream job just because other 3000 are applying to it". If you have a minimal fit you should try. Because selecting a profile is not a matter of competition (IMO) is a matter of fitting the role (technical, cultural, and others that the company may use) it does not matter if is 1 or more candidates.

Dear @Pac0 I never said that showing the number of application was good or bad, I just said that using this as a matter of competition is wrong. And about having information to have lavarege in a negotiation is like 101 for negotiation. But having a information that everyone has is not a lavarege, is it?

Again, if the company is pressuring you with the "we have more candidates and if you want it you have to low your salary......" There are multiple analysis within this situation:
 1. The company works with pressure and low budget, is not looking for the best employee.
 2. The company works with a lot of negotiation and what to know how you handle it.
 3. The company wants you badly but don't want you to know that.
 4. The company want to measure how much you want to work for they.
  .
  .
  .

The question is what kind of professional you are, what kind of person you are and how you sell yourself, are you willing to negotiate and know how to do it, are you willing to low salary for a dream job, etc. As I said before and repete, each company has its own process, culture and problem, there's no formula.

Comment: LinkedIn does it and provides statistics as to your comparison with competitors for the job...not saying it's a positive pattern, just that some online job search alternatives already do provide this info. it provides some insight into what kind of people are likely going to be accepted in the role

Comment: I gotta disagree with you, Bruno.  I have yet to see a recruiter actually do something other than gatekeep a position.  The value they bring to the hiring process is to submit their recruits as is, with almost no vetting whatsoever.  I keep trying, and they keep failing.

Comment: It depends on the company culture. As I told you each company has its own process and culture. There's no formula.